# Beginner's Language app

Tags: iphone, python, android

Hi I'm a techie with no programing experience. I know html and css, but I'd like to someday be able to make an app for my phone (I have an android) and possibly mobile websites.

I made learning a programing language and creating a mobile app a goal for my job, and now my boss would like me to pick a programing language to learn. I found a free open course from MIT (http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/) called introduction to computer science. In the course they teach python, but more importantly it seems they teach how to think like a programmer.

When I told my boss about the free online course she didn't think that Python was an appropriate language for me to learn. She'd like me to learn a language that is more similar to one used to make Phone apps. Does anyone out there know a better language for me to pick up that would be similar to Android or iPhone's App language.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A few things stood out to me as your goals:

1. You want formal training on how to program (this is independent of a language)
2. You want to learn how to develop apps for a mobile device
3. Your boss is on board with goals 1 and 2, but wants to see the best return on her investment.

I think the easiest way for you to meet all of these goals is to start learning how to program with **Java**.  Java is often used in introductory computer science courses, so you should be able to learn the language and programming concepts in parallel.  Once you have that foundation, you will be able to start learning **Android** development, since Android applications are built with the Java language.

You can start off by reading some of the resources from Oracle: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html

And there are plenty of good intro books too:

- [Thinking In Java by Bruce Eckel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131872486)
- [Head First Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009208)

There is nothing wrong with starting off by learning Python.  Once you have a good grasp of programming fundamentals, you can learn new languages relatively quickly.  However, from your boss's perspective, there is more value in paying for you to learn a language for mobile development **and** programming at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Learn to program first before learning how to develop for the iPhone.  That will give you a much better chance at success.  Python a perfectly good language for learning to program, especially in the context of an Intro to CS course environment.  But any intro programming language environment will do (even one designed for kids).

Once you're comfortable writing non-trivial programs in Python (or whatever first computer language you choose), learning Objective C and the iOS APIs (or Java and the Android APIs) will become much **much** easier, compared with starting from scratch and zero programming background.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a good beginning language, but you need to ensure that you do more than just course work.

Why not just run through tutorials on Android development right off the bat? If you are worried about wasting time by not using Java immediately, then why not just start there?

Comment: If you have never programmed before, I think you would be far better off working through 1 intro class, even if it is python, before trying to tackle Android development.  If you don't even know what a variable is, let alone, objects, functions, etc, you'll probably just get frustrated.

Comment: An intro to Java would teach that - and OP said he didn't want to waste time on Python. I think learning programming, regardless of your approach, is an exercise in persistent frustration ;)

Answer (score 0):

Android uses Java, and iPhone uses Objective C.

If you need a quick solution, try learning Java and using a framework like NimbleKit for iPhone, which lets you build your app out of HTML/CSS + Javascript.

http://www.nimblekit.com

Answer (score 0):

If time is short and you need results to motivate you I would suggest this O'Reilly [e-book](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449383268/) (http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449383268/) that is tailored to a reader with HTML, CSS, and Javascript (jQuery) skillset. Alternatively, the App Inventor (http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/index.html) also looks like a perfect way for you to dive in and explore; it is designed to be non-programmer friendly.

After you have some quick success, you might then be interested implementing some feature that is not readily supported by these two environments. Then I agree that the traditional approach in taking a course and learning a language would be a good long term investment.